# Bootstrap table in php i.e under <?php ?>

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a table in php but i think i doing some mistake in the syntax.

```
<? php 
echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">'
echo '<colgroup>'
echo '<col class="col-xs-1">'
echo '<col class="col-xs-7">'
echo '</colgroup>'
echo '<thead>'
echo '<tr>'
echo '<th>Date</th>'
echo '<th>Title and Description</th>'
echo '</tr>'
echo '</thead>'
echo '<tbody>'
for ($num = 0; $num <= $data1; $num++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$data1[$num] - > find('a', 0).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data[$num] - > find('a', 0).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>'
echo '</table>' ?>
```

Comment: Please add more information...

Comment: <?php 
    echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">'
    echo '<colgroup>'
    echo '<col class="col-xs-1">'
    echo '<col class="col-xs-7">'
    echo '</colgroup>'
    echo '<thead>'
    echo '<tr>'
    echo '<th>Date</th>'
    echo '<th>Title and Description</th>'
    echo '</tr>'
    echo '</thead>'
    echo '<tbody>'
    for($num=0;$num<=$data1;$num++)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$data1[$num]->find('a', 0).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$data[$num]->find('a', 0).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';   
    }        
    echo '</tbody>'
    echo '</table>'
?>

Comment: @andrew please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: you missed a lot of semi colons at the end of each line

Comment: ok thanks any more mistake?

Comment: I got the result but table was not there. It is in plain text.

Comment: @tenstormavi - Please add some details about what you want to have happen vs what is actually happening. Right now your question seems to be "I don't know the syntax of the language I'm supposed to be using, so someone fix it for me." which isn't really a question, it's just a request that will never help a future reader on StackOverflow.

Comment: Are you sure your webserver supports PHP and/or is installed correctly?

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestion. I want to create a table in which i can show the output of the php code but no striped table is showing instead of it is showing in a normal table.

Answer (score 2):

After each statement, you must use a semicolon (`;`), you missed them on all of your statements.
Also, you can mix HTML and PHP. Which makes it a lot cleaner:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="col-xs-1">
    <col class="col-xs-7">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Title and Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    for ($num = 0; $num <= $data1; $num++) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$data1[$num]->find('a', 0).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$data[$num]->find('a', 0).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I got the result but table was not there. It is in plain text.

Comment: What is plain text? your data? the php? be more clear in your question. We aren't sorcerers, we can't see you page from our minds. You really need to add more details here if you want us to help you.

Comment: I have used this but again it is in plain text no table is created.

Comment: It should be in a striped table but it is not. And showing the result in a normal table .

Comment: Are you sure you' re including the right stylesheet?

Comment: Yup i am sure.. i think the problem is in the php code.. but can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //try this 

<?php 
echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
echo '<colgroup>';
echo '<col class="col-xs-1">';
echo '<col class="col-xs-7">';
echo '</colgroup>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Date</th>';
echo '<th>Title and Description</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
for ($num = 0; $num <= $data1; $num++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$data1[$num]->find('a', 0).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data[$num]->find('a', 0).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
 ?>

//or        

            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <colxgroup>
              <col class="col-xs-1">
              <col class="col-xs-7">
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Title and Description</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php 
            for ($num = 0; $num <= $data1; $num++) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$data1[$num]->find('a', 0).'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data[$num]->find('a', 0).'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>

        //OR


    Always use semicolon (;) at end of the statement. in php tag dont use space  <?php /*your code*/ ?>
```